# git diff: ignore renaming of variables

Tags: git, ignore, git-diff

While doing some refactoring, I renamed a variable from `oldName` to `newName`. Is there a way to tell the `git diff` command to ignore differences where `oldName` is now `newName`? I want to do this to focus in on only the other non-trivial changes. If this is possible, can I also specify more than one variable renaming to ignore, e.g., ignore changes from `oldName1` to `newName1` and from `oldName2` to `newName2` ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He is very correct, but of course you can grep the output of diff.  Not the same thing, but depending on the magnitude of the change, perhaps usable.

```
git diff | egrep -v 'oldName|newName' | egrep '^[+-]'
```

In general, you should try to have your commits be one commit per concept.  You can also split your pre-commits using `git add -p`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the -I option of diff? Here's a way how to do this:

```
    env GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF='perl -e "system(qw{diff -I the_pattern_to_ignore -u}, @ARGV[0,1])"' git diff
```

perl is needed here to throw away the extra arguments git provides to the external diff program.

Answer (score 0):

OK. selckin in Git's IRC channel told me that it's not possible.

Comment: There may not be a single git command that does this. But what I've learned from reading questions in the [git] tag on SO, is that there's *always* a way to do what you want, if you know a little bash scripting.